# Oracle difference between 2 dates whose datatype is CHAR(23 BYTE)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, select

How to find diff between below 2 dates in minutes, both data types is CHAR using SQL

```
2019-10-31 10:23:05.927 
2019-10-30 11:20:05.500
```

Comment: Dont store dates are chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_date()` to turn both strings to `date`s (ignoring the millisecond part), then subtract them. This gives you a numeric value that represents the difference between the dates as a number of days, that you can then convert to hours:

```
(
    to_date(substr(col1, 1, 19), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    - to_date(substr(col2, 1, 19), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
) * 24 * 60
```

If you do want to include the millisecond part, then it gets lengthy. You can convert the strings to `timestamp`s using `to_timestamp()`, then substract them; this produces an interval, from which you need to extract each part.

```
extract(hour from 
    to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
    - to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
) * 60
+ extract(minute from 
    to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
    - to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
)
+ extract(second from 
    to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
    - to_timestamp(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
) / 60
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but both option not giving accurate time difference in minutes, I tried below from your extract option and its giving time difference, in minutes.                    (extract(DAY FROM (to_timestamp(col1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') - to_timestamp(col2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')))*24*60)+ 
   (extract(HOUR FROM (to_timestamp(col1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') - to_timestamp(col2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')))*60)+
 (extract(MINUTE FROM (to_timestamp(col1,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') - to_timestamp(col2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3')))) AS min_dff,

Comment: @Tushar: I just fixed the second expression (it was giving a result in hours rather than in minutes).